# compare function syntax error

Tags: javascript, syntax

I am trying to make a rock paper scissors game for code academy and I was told to create a function for compare(). I have written the following code:

```
function compare(choice1,choice2){
if (choice1 == choice2){
    console.log("The result is a tie!");
} else{
    console.log("the computer wins");
}
```

when I run it, "The result is a tie!" appears twice but I get an error code saying "Oops, try again! Your compare function does not return 'The result is a tie!' when there is a tie." I know there is something wrong with my syntax but I am very new so I don't know where. Any help?

Comment: You're not actually `return`ing anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not returning from the function, you're logging the result. After either of the `console.log` statements, send back a `return`

```
console.log("The result is a tie!");
return true; //or whatever
```

Comment: I ended up doing  return "the result is a tie!" and that worked. thanks!